# Using Rexter API to interact with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin, titan, tinkerpop

Is there a way to interact with a neo4j graph db (running externally HA mode) via Rexter API. Neo4j's REST api is great but using Rexter makes my application completely agnostic of the remote graph db implementation stack. This will enable me to swap in other tinkerpop based graph db stacks like titan without affecting/changing my application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Neo4jHaGraph` Blueprints implementation:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Neo4jHa-Implementation

Here's some instructions for connecting using Rexster:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Specific-Graph-Configurations#neo4j-high-availability-cluster

Comment: Tried it without much luck. Are you sure this works with neo4j 1.9.X. They dont use zookeeper anymore and i see warnings about zookeeper in rexster server logs

Comment: Should work with 1.9.x.  I cleaned up the wiki by removing references to zookeeper.  As for the errors you're seeing, it looks like there is  a minor Rexster bug in there for HA configuration.  Can you please try to workaround it by simply adding a fake entry to your rexster.xml for `<ha.zoo_keeper_servers>nothing</ha.zoo_keeper_servers>`?  That should get rexster to at least think that it's there and allow the configuration to continue to execute.

Comment: Just committed a fix: https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/commit/405bb966c277e6d8b4f156c378c3aff29eac75b5 as part of the 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: This way the rexster did come up but it was unable contact the cluster initial hosts. There was no errors logged but i found the neo graph to be completely empty from rexster console. Though i know that the cluster has millions of vertices and edges.